# Partial results in Solr

Tags: solr

Let's assume a query with the following words in Solr: yellow, blue, green.

I would like to return documents matching in this order:

- all documents that contain: yellow AND blue AND green
- then documents that contain (yellow AND blue) OR (yellow AND green) OR (blue AND green)
- then documents that contain yellow OR blue OR  green

In short: documents matching all 3 terms, then matching 2 terms, then single matches.

How can I structure the query for this?

Comment: did you tried boosting ...?

Comment: Boosting would work to return documents that have yellow first, then blue and then green for example; but it wouldn't help with partial queries.

Comment: What's your field type for the field..?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the default behavior when searching against a single field. The more optional SHOULD clauses are matched - the higher the score.

However, if you are using Dismax or eDismax and terms match against different fields, you will get competing scores and only the highest will get picked. This could cause some terms in one field shadow the presence of additional terms in a different field and give you possible different order.

One strategy to try in those situations is the [tie](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thetie%28TieBreaker%29Parameter) (Tie Breaker) parameter, which will take into account scores from those non-maximum-score field matches. Try setting it to 1 for the extreme effect and see if the results are more like what you expected.